# Display link on template when user is a staff member in Django

Tags: python, django

I am kind a newbie to Django, and I have a navigation bar in which I need to display a link only when the user is a staff member. The following is my navigation bar:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="{% url 'pledges:preferences' %}">{% trans 'Preferences' %}</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'pledges:account' %}">{% trans 'My Account' %}</a></li>
      {# The following link should be displayed just to staff members #}
      <li><a href="{% url dashboard %}">{% trans 'Dashboard' %}</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'pledges:logout' %}">{% trans 'Log Out' %}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas how can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your view it might be as simple as:

```
{% if request.user.is_staff %}
  <li><a href="{% url dashboard %}">{% trans 'Dashboard' %}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you so much. This is working like charm. It is exactly what I wanted, and I was worried about having to pass something in the context.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Here are the relevant docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates

Answer (score 7):

It's as simple as:

```
{# The following link should be displayed just to staff members #}
{% if request.user.is_staff %}
    <li><a href="{% url dashboard %}">{% trans 'Dashboard' %}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

where `user` is the relevant user model, depending if you use Django's vanilla User or you have overriding it.